# Displaying the image of choice via shared links eg Facebook like?

Tags: html, facebook-like

If I share the link to my page via Facebook the wrong image appears. How can I control which image is displayed when my page is shared in social media such as facebook and previewed:

[image]

The image of the envelope displayed above is what I'd like to control.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try put this code in tag head of page that you want to share, it work in my web:

```
<head>
<meta name="title" content="title" />
<meta name="description" content="description" />
<!-- deafult image for fb share --> 
<link rel="image_src" href="http://web.com/myweb.png" />
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to use this code for dynamic image serving `<link rel="{{image_url}}" href="{{image_url}}" />` and I wonder what the difference is between the parameters `rel =` and `href=` if href is a link to the page or to the image(?).

Comment: Mmm.. if you use this for dynamic image, code should be like this: <link rel="image_src" href="{{image_url}}" />

:)

Comment: Thanks Fredy! I'm now using the code you suggest. If you want to check out an actual page where the output is the URL is http://www.montao.com.br/vi/4434188.html